# How to calculate array while rendering [Vue.js] - Infinite loop error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

This is my code in parent component:

```
                   <div
                            v-for="measurement
                             in measurements"
                            :key="measurement.id"
                   >
                            <graph-component
                                :value="valueOfMeasurement(measurement)"
                            ></graph-component>
                  </div>
```

I send props  `value` to child component `graph-component`.
`:value` should send array to `graph-component` but I get error `You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.`.

Method`valueOfMeasurement(measurement)` is:

```
methods:{

     valueOfMeasurement(measurement) {
                this.arrayOfValues.length=0;
                this.counter=0;
    
                for( this.counter;this.counter<this.message.feeds.length;this.counter++)
                {
                     this.arrayOfValues.push(this.message.feeds[this.counter]["field" + measurement.fieldId]);
                }
                return this.arrayOfValues;
                
            }
}
```

Im beginner to Vue.js and I assume that I get this error because I push new elements to array, but I can't find other way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a possible infinite loop because you are mutating state during the render. Specifically, you are calling the `valueOfMeasurement` method during the render (i.e. within the template) which is modifying the component state (`this.arrayOfValues` and `this.counter`). This will trigger Vue to re-render again, which then mutates the state again, and so on infinitely.

Why are `arrayOfValues` and `counter` local state? You're just clearing them each time the method is called anyway, so it seems they should just be local variables within the method. **But**... that depends on if `<graph-component>` mutates these arrays; if so you should pre-compute all of this data ahead of time outside of the template, perhaps when `measurements` is first set or in `created` hook, etc.

Comment: That's it. I got wrong idea that I need to declare it in data so it won't give me infinity loop.